# ToggleButtons Fragments SharedPref

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am teaching myself how to use Fragments and SharedPreferences. I am creating an app that uses a Navigation Drawer to change between the fragments.

In fragment A I have 8 toggle buttons. When the user leaves fragment A for B and then returns I need the toggle buttons that were switched to stay that way until it is manually reset by the user. The toggle and the reset work fine, however I have not been successful in my many attempts to get SharedPref to hold the state of the button.

I think this might be the prblem, becasue it is calling "new" each time the menu item is selected. If so, how do I get around it?

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_carb:
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,
                       new  CarbFragment()).commit();
                break;
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    ToggleButton toggleButton, toggleButton1, toggleButton2, toggleButton3, toggleButton4, toggleButton5, toggleButton6, toggleButton7;
    boolean selected, tb;
    SharedPreferences preferences;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView =findViewById(R.id.navView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("checkedState", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(preferences.contains("tbpref")){
            selected = preferences.getBoolean("tbpref", true);
        }
       }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_carb:
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,
                       new  CarbFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_cal:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,
                        new CalFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
```

**FragmentA**

```
public class CarbFragment extends Fragment {

ToggleButton toggleButton, toggleButton1, toggleButton2, toggleButton3, toggleButton4, toggleButton5, toggleButton6, toggleButton7;
Button reset;
boolean selected, tb;
SharedPreferences preferences;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ConstraintLayout rootView = (ConstraintLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carb_count, container, false);


    toggleButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    toggleButton1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    toggleButton2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    toggleButton3 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
    toggleButton4 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton4);
    toggleButton5 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton5);
    toggleButton6 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton6);
    toggleButton7 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton7);
    reset = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           toggleButton.setChecked(false);
           toggleButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 153, 153));
           toggleButton1.setChecked(false);
           toggleButton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 219, 153));
           toggleButton2.setChecked(false);
           toggleButton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 153));
           toggleButton3.setChecked(false);
           toggleButton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(153, 255, 153));
           toggleButton4.setChecked(false);
           toggleButton4.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(153, 153, 255));
           toggleButton5.setChecked(false);
           toggleButton5.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 153, 255));
           toggleButton6.setChecked(false);
           toggleButton6.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
           toggleButton7.setChecked(false);
           toggleButton7.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(204, 204, 204));

           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ready to go again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toast.show();
       }
   });



    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nom Nom Nom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("tbpref", true);
                editor.apply();
            }
            else{
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("tbpref", false);
                editor.apply();
            }


        }
    });
    toggleButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleButton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You've got this!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });


    toggleButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleButton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Look at you go!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    toggleButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleButton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You are crushing this!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    toggleButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleButton4.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Killin' IT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    toggleButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleButton5.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Carbs don't control you!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    toggleButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleButton6.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You're so awesome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    toggleButton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleButton7.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Kickin' butt and taking names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Any help that can be provided is very appreciated. I have looked at several answers here on SO and none of them seem to fit my issue. I tried implementing pieces of answers but they don't seem to work for me either.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only write the state to the shared preferences and don't read it from them inside your fragment. In order to achieve this you have to do something like this in your `onCreateView` method:

```
boolean isChecked = preferences.getBoolean("tbpref");
toggleButton.setChecked(isChecked);
```

Comment: thank you. I was able to get the button to read correctly, however it is not saving the formatting. When clicked they should turn dark grey and stay dark grey until the user resets it.